# C# Substracting DateTimes is giving unrealistic result

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Here is my scenario:

Player places their finger or mouse on the “Home Position” marker at the bottom of the screen.

A timer begins counting to 500ms, if the user does not lift their finger or marker in that time the holdTimerElapsed is fired.

Inside this method, we display the next marker, delay for anywhere between 500ms to 1 second (so the user has a chance to see the next target). After the delay, an audio “GO” is played and a timer is started.

Inside the timer start method:

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer.Interval = ConfigurationService.GameConfig.MarkerTimeLimit;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
}
```

We log the "start time" of those movement. If the user is able to click the next target that popped up within the alotted time (4.5 seconds) we call the stop timer method:

```
private void StopTimer()
{
    stopTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer.Stop();
}
```

My problem:

"Randomly" the result of:

```
TimeSpan time = stopTime - startTime;
```

Minus the 500ms hold time will be an unrealistic 2-5 milliseconds - an impossible movement time for anyone but a bot.

I am at a complete loss for why the date times would be so close together giving such a small result.

More Code:

```
private void HandleMarkerClick(ScatterCircle selectedCircle)
{
    StopTimer();
    selectedCircle.Aquired = true;
    aquiredTrainingCircles.Add(selectedCircle);
    TimeSpan time = stopTime - startTime;
    // movementTime here 'randomly' ends up as <10ms
    long movementTime = (long) time.TotalMilliseconds - ConfigurationService.GameConfig.MarkerHoldTime;  
}
```

I am only dealing with milliseconds in this case for bench-marking movements, and they need to be relatively accurate, anything less than 100ms is generally "to fast to be real"

Comment: I suggest you use `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime.Now` for this...

Comment: Also, it's not the subtraction of `DateTime` values that is the problem - it's which `DateTime` values you're starting with that is causing the issue.

Comment: I will switch over and try out Stopwatch. It is odd to me that it works the majority of the time but every once in a while it comes up all bad.

Comment: I think that you expect players to strictly follow your rules instead randomly do whatever they want - unless there life and death decision on outcome I'd expect at least some players to randomly click, swipe, whatever else ignoring all your precise timing and directions...

Comment: Alexei; the HandleMarkerClick method is only called in the event that the player meets the preconditions for clicking on a marker - I do agree that users will do whatever they want though :)

Comment: Are you sure your `StartTimer` is not unintentionally called  ?

Comment: Vincent: I checked, there is only one spot it is called and it would also give an audio signal that would be obvious if that was the case. The plain timer.start is not called anywhere else either.

Comment: Are you getting that result before or after the MarkerHoldTime substract?

Comment: JAT: The result is set inside StopTimer() which happens before the subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an end to this question, I took Jon Skeet's advice and switched to the `Stopwatch` class. The client was still having inconsistent results.

I was unable to reproduce the issue, and long story short, the client was running the application on a laptop in power saving mode which I believe was causing the inconsistencies.

Switching from power saver mode to high performance seemed to fix the issue for the most part.

Comment: That is really, really weird.